# How to use storyboard reference with cocoa pods?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want to using cocoa pods create a private pods that using storyboard.   What i do is creating a simple pods that only have a Test.storyboard( in which have a empty vc scene ,and its storyboard id is SecondVC ) and a ViewController named SecondVC. In the pod's example to using storyboard reference to show the secondVC, but there is a error says:Not enough arguments provided; where is the input document to operate on? I search for the solution via google but no use. Could someone help? Here is the detail:

[The project detail screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDfMl.png)

[The error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWVAQ.png)

And in the podspec like this:

```
  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'

  s.source_files = 'SecondModule/Classes/**/*'

  s.resource_bundles = {
    'SecondModule' => ['SecondModule/Classes/*.storyboard']
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because the file name is SecondViewController, but the Referenced ID says SecondVC?

[image]

This is how the placeholder text looks like. It is asking for the initial VC. Can you set it to SecondViewController?

Comment: Thanks for reply , but I set the ReferenceID to SecondVC in the Test.storyboard. So there is no problem here. @7to4

Comment: I think we're talking about different things. In the first image you posted, the top right corner has a "Referenced ID". This is the ViewController's name. But your Pod doesn't have a class called SecondVC. Can you change that parameter to SecondViewController and check?

Comment: The reference id is not the name of ViewController. It's the unique identifier of ViewController, and i have set this to SecondVC in the scene in the Test.Storyboard in my pods. I'm sorry for i couldn't post image because i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I have done what you suggest , but still no use.  You can create two VC in storyboard, let's say A and B. Click B and select identity inspector, there is identity section where you can set the storyboardID, type BVC. And create a storyboard reference and set the reference id to BVC.  That's could make the storyboard reference be the B Controller. And that's what i did in my pods.